# Django: Model __init__() is called on every update

Tags: python, django

I'm having a rather mystifying problem in one of my models. I've overridden `__init__` as follows:

```
class Program(models.Model)
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Program, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for m in Milestone.objects.all():
            try:
                ProgramMilestone.objects.create(milestone = m, program = self)
            except IntegrityError: # The link already exists.
                pass
```

where ProgramMilestone is a linker table (using `through='...'`) between `Milestone` and `Program`.

I would like all `Milestones` to be added to a `Program` only upon program creation, but right now whenever I even open the Program in Django's admin interface, it runs the `for m...` loop (making it impossible to remove any `ProgramMilestone` objects in Django admin, since they'll just get remade upon refresh).

Am I misunderstanding what `__init__` does, and if so, how can I create this behavior (i.e. one-off code that only runs upon instantiation)?

Comment: In python, __init__ is called whenever an instance of a class is created. Therefore, __init__ is being called when you query for a Program as well as when you first create it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I got you correctly, you want to run some code when a program is created.

You can use the `post_save` signal and check for the `created` flag.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save

By having your code listen to that signal, you can run your code whenever a Program is created, and not changed.

Comment: That's correct, and thanks for the link, I'll check it out. So is it standard behavior for `__init__()` to be called like `save()`? What's the difference if that's how `__init__()` behaves?

Comment: `__init__()` is run whenever you instantiate a Python object in memory, so it's run when you load objects from the database or create new ones and you shouldn't rely on it for this kind of stuff (especially for "on modification" operations, because you might already have the object instantiated somewhere). `save()` is a completely different, and Django-specific method.

Answer (score 3):

The `__init__` method is called whenever an in-memory Program object is created.  This happens when you read Programs from the database, along with times that you are truly creating new Program objects on disk.

Comment: Ahh, I see... I didn't consider that `__init__` referred to in-memory object creation as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That *is* instantiation. Instantiation is when a Python object is created, either from scratch or by using values from the database.

You probably want to override the `save` method - in your version, set a flag if `self.pk` is None, call the super class's `save`, then run your code if the flag is set.